# Не могу понять как сделать "одностороннюю синхронизацию" в системе

Tags: python, windows, copy

Думаю начать издали. Пользовались гугл диском и яндекс диском. Есть проблема в том, что раз в день постоянно исчезают какие-то файлы. Просто без следа(нет ни в удаленных файлах, ни в истории). Придумал некую схему, которую не понимаю как реализовать: сделать локалку, где хранятся файлы, они синхронизированы с dropbox, ну а уже с локалки они копируются в другую директорию. Архитектура идет по принципу: Папка, в которой все -- Папка клиента -- n-ое количество папок/файлов по типу pdf dox jpg. Папок клиентов так же не мало и они пополняются. В папках клиента могут меняться файлы, редактироваться, удаляться. Так вот вопрос как сделать некую одностороннюю синхронизацию, чтобы когда в главной директории происходит какое-либо действие(или хотя бы просто добавление нового файла) - то оно зеркалило бы это в другой директории. Не прошу готовый код, просто помогите куда копнуть, с чем возиться. Нагуглил только модуль shutil, но чего-то не могу понять как можно с его помощью решить эту проблему. Подойдет даже просто если есть какое-либо приложение, которое поможет решить задачу.

Вес головной папки около 8 гб.

Comment: Вам для начала нужно отследить события файловой системы. Так как у вас, похоже Windows, вам подойдет watchdog. Можете посмотреть вот эту статью: https://codeby.net/threads/gorshochek-meda-dlja-kollegi-sozdaem-lovushku-na-python.79849/. Ничего особого, но некоторое представление даст.

Comment: `robocopy` + `scheduler`?